# Cancel task in c#

Tags: c#, task, cancellation

I´m still learning to code, and I'm making a new project with MDI forms (C# and Visual Studio 2019). In mdichild, I launched a task, but if the form is unloaded, the task still remains. I would like to know how cancel the task, even on a cancel button click.

The code:

```
private async void BuscaActualizaciones()
{
    await Task.Run(() => DoLongThing());
}

private void DoLongThing()
{
    //some hard stuff
}

private void BtnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //In here i launch the task with hard stuff
    BuscaActualizaciones();
}
```

This code works perfectly, but I need to cancel in some events, and I don't know how.

I tried some home-made tricks, and read on Google about task cancellation, but all of them used `Task` in other way that I don't understand. I'm still learning, and it is my first time with tasks.

Comment: The proper way to do that is to pass around [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-7.0), and react to it inside the Task.

Comment: I've removed the Visual Studio 2019 tag because this question isn't about using Visual Studio, so it's irrelevant.

Comment: First, you need that to be `private async void BtnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` and `await BuscaActualizaciones()` which needs to be `private async Task BuscaActualizaciones()`. Then we can look further...

Comment: So you want to cancel the `DoLongThing` in a non cooperative fashion? You want to "kill" it, so to speak, at an arbitrary point during its execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the correct solution will use a `CancellationToken`. However, you don't want to pass it to `Task.Run`; you want to pass it to `DoLongThing`, as such:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new ();

private async void BuscaActualizaciones()
{
  await Task.Run(() => DoLongThing(cts.Token)); 
}

private void DoLongThing(CancellationToken token)
{
  ...
  token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}

private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  cts.Cancel();
}
```

Polling for cancellation (`ThrowIfCancellationRequested`) is common for CPU-bound methods that need to periodically check if they're canceled. I have a [blog post that goes into more details on the subject](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2022/03/cancellation-4-polling.html).

Comment: Thank you Stephen. One question.. where i have to dispose cts?

Comment: Since it's a class-level variable, make the class disposable and dispose the cts when the class is disposed.

Comment: Thank you Stephen for your help. A final question : if  DoLongThing(CancellationToken token) returns for example a list of objects, or an integer , how can i get this value from BuscaActualizaciones() or from task? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As @freakish pointed out in the comment, the proper way to do this is using a [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-7.0). Here is a simple example, assuming you have button which cancels the task when clicked:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

private async Task BuscaActualizaciones()
{
    await Task.Run(DoLongThing, cts.Token); 
}

private Task DoLongThing() // <-- needs to return a Task
{
    //some hard stuff
    cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    //some hard stuff
}

private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cts.Cancel();  // <-- here is the cancallation
}
```

I also strongly recommend recommend the documentation regarding ["Asynchronous programming with async and await"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: Please also fix `private async void BuscaActualizaciones()?` ... OP is still learning.

Comment: and how concretly?

Comment: You keep using that cancellation token there...  [A Tour of Task, Part 9: Delegate Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html) by Stephen Cleary.

Comment: This will not cancel the execution of the `DoLongThing` method. Quote from docs [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0): _A cancellation token allows the work to be cancelled if it has not yet started_.

Answer (score -1):

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource ();

private async void BuscaActualizaciones()
{
    await Task.Run(() => DoLongThing(), cts.Token); 
}

private Void DoLongThing() 
{
    //some hard stuff

       if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
              {
                 throw new TaskCanceledException();
              }
}

private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cts.Cancel();  // <-- here is the cancellation
}
```

It´s working perfectly. thank you to all with help. The cts.IsCancellationRequested I read in google. Thank you .

Comment: `async void` -- working perfectly.

Comment: I don´t know why the negative vote....

Comment: @Dav3 You shouldn't return void with an async method as it will swallow any exceptions that occur within the method.  This means it will "work perfectly" even when it fails.  Async Void can be used for EVENT HANDLERS (e.g. _click), but everything else should always return a Task.